# Send images to twitter through code

Tags: iphone

[image]

HI all,
can we post images with tweets in twittter through code in iphone????
Check the screen shots

I am using busyAgent.this helps me to tweet wiothout posting images, i need to send images to at the time of tweeting

Guidence
regards

[image]

Comment: we're not going to write your code for you (although some on here are **very** generous and may well do, but don't count on it!). You need to at least show us what you've tried. As someone else said recently, *we're not code monkeys*.

Comment: Thanks for ur useful comment....
BTW i am able to tweet through code, wat i m trying to do is, to send images with tweets.

Regards

Comment: well then show us *what you've tried* - it's always better to have a starting point as someone could correct your code, rather than pointing you at - for example - a library or API that's utterly different to the one you're already using =)

Comment: check my question, i updated it with screenshots

Comment: From the looks of things you just need to get the locations of your images (stored on your phone) - there are many guides how to do this, they'll just be stored in a directory somewhere - and post the image to a image hosting site through their API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a few APIs for this (for what I think you are trying to do?)

- [The Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/--)  For posting a tweet
- An API of many of the popular twitter image hosting/sharing websites, for example [The Twitpic API](http://twitpic.com/api.do)

  - This will allow you to upload the image to their site (through code) and get a URL in return, containing the location of your uploaded image

Then you just need to do something like

- Upload your image using the api of your image sharing site and storing the URL somewhere
- Formulate your tweet message with the URL in it
- Use the Twitter API to connect to your account (or whoever is using your application and has supplied their login credentials)
- Post the tweet

Comment: Thanks djhworld,

i can tweet through my code, its running absolutely fine.
i just need to knw how can i also send images to twitter.

regards

Comment: shishir - What I'm saying should allow you to do this. Unless I'm out of touch (things move really fast these days!) I don't think Twitter hosts any images, they partner up with image hosting sites instead

Twitpic is one of them, you send them an image, they do a bit of processing and return a URL telling you where that image is. Then all you need to do is post your tweet with the URL in it.

e.g. "This is my cat http://<twitpic-URL>"

Comment: actually, from the looks of it the Twitpic API allows you to upload the image and post a tweet at the same time, so that's killing two birds with one stone there!